# How to assign JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm New in AngularJS. i'm trying to assign JSON objects and i'm using Object.assign to assign JSON objects. But I can't get the result that i want
Please help me to get the result.

```js
'use strict'

let one ={"Start":"11","Dashboard":"1","Settings":"2","Support":"3","Trunk":"4","Routing":"5","Solutions":"6","Accounting":"7","Statistic":"8","Marketing":"9","Profile":"10"};
let two = {"Settings":{"Basic Settings":"1","Number Range":"2","Employess":"3","Message Fulfillment":"4"},"Support":{"All Contacts":"5","Detail Approval":"6","Incomplete Signup":"7","Settings":"8"},"Trunk":{"My Tickets":"9","All Tickets":"10"}};

let three = {"Settings":{"Basic Settings":{"My Information":"1","Bank Information":"2"}}};

let four = Object.assign({}, one, two, three);

console.log(JSON.stringify(four));
```

Comment: i need this :-
{"Start":"11","Dashboard":"1","Settings":{"Basic Settings":{"My Information":"1","Bank Information":"2"},"Number Range":"2","Employess":"3","Message Fulfillment":"4"},"Support":{"All Contacts":"5","Detail Approval":"6","Incomplete Signup":"7","Settings":"8"},"Trunk":{"My Tickets":"9","All Tickets":"10"},"Routing":"5","Solutions":"6","Accounting":"7","Statistic":"8","Marketing":"9","Profile":"10","Basic Settings":{"My Information":"1","Bank Information":"2"}}

Comment: you got your answer?

Comment: @deepgagan did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
function mergeObjects() {
    var merged_obj = {};
    for (i in arguments) {
        obj = arguments[i];
        for (j in obj) {
                merged_obj[j] = obj[j];
        }
    }
    return merged_obj;
}

var one ={"Start":"11","Dashboard":"1","Settings":"2","Support":"3","Trunk":"4","Routing":"5","Solutions":"6","Accounting":"7","Statistic":"8","Marketing":"9","Profile":"10"};
var two = {"Settings":{"Basic Settings":"1","Number Range":"2","Employess":"3","Message Fulfillment":"4"},"Support":{"All Contacts":"5","Detail Approval":"6","Incomplete Signup":"7","Settings":"8"},"Trunk":{"My Tickets":"9","All Tickets":"10"}};

var three = {"Settings":{"Basic Settings":{"My Information":"1","Bank Information":"2"}}};

var mergedObj = mergeObjects(one, two, three);
console.log(mergedObj);
```

Comment: it doesn't show these values :- 
"Number Range":"2","Employess":"3","Message Fulfillment":"4"

Answer (score 0):

You can extend objects with `$.extend(a, b);` using jQuery but as you are using angularjs, you can use core javascript

```
let one ={"Start":"11","Dashboard":"1","Settings":"2","Support":"3","Trunk":"4","Routing":"5","Solutions":"6","Accounting":"7","Statistic":"8","Marketing":"9","Profile":"10"};
let two = {"Settings":{"Basic Settings":"1","Number Range":"2","Employess":"3","Message Fulfillment":"4"},"Support":{"All Contacts":"5","Detail Approval":"6","Incomplete Signup":"7","Settings":"8"},"Trunk":{"My Tickets":"9","All Tickets":"10"}};

let three   =   {"Settings":{"Basic Settings":{"My Information":"1","Bank Information":"2"}}};


function jsonExtend(a, b) {
 for (var key in b) {
  a[key] = b[key];
 }
 return a;
}

var output = {};
output = jsonExtend(output, one);
output = jsonExtend(output, two);
output = jsonExtend(output, three);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: output doesn't show :- 
"Number Range":"2","Employess":"3","Message Fulfillment":"4"

Comment: When concatenating objects, attributes got duplicated, so third one override second.

Comment: As duplicate attribute do not exist on a object, you can array concatenate those objects.

Comment: i got these values dynamically so how can i use array concatenate. can you please help me to use this?

Comment: I just mean that you store those on a single array. like 
`var output = []; output.push(one,two,three);` But as you only know how you retrieving those values, you can yourself store in a appropriate way.